# one-liner to exclude patterns with exceptions

Tags: bash, awk, sed, text-processing

My goal is to make an elegant **one-liner**.

**Inputs**:

Source file, containing a list of strings:

```
foo123
bar12356
foo999
var8292
bar922
link991
bar8
var000
```

File with blacklist patterns:

```
bar
link
```

Whitelist file (can contain multiple entries):

```
bar922
```

**Task**:
We need to remove the strings according to the patterns in the blacklist, retaining the precise matches from the whitelist. A catch is we need to both *keep the output in the same order as in the origin file*, and we *shouldn't add the whitelist strings if they don't exist in the initial file*.

**Output**:

```
foo123
foo999
var8292
bar922
var000
```

Comment: Where's the commands or code you've attempted?

Comment: I have a working multiline solution with ifs, but it doesn't look very elegant. The simplest is just removing the blacklist pattern: `grep -v -f blacklist.txt <source.txt`, but neither exclude nor -P (pregs) do not stick together with it. I also have a stupid solution which just works, but doesn't satisfy me at all: I duplicate each whitelist entry in a source file, and then remove the unique patterns.

Comment: Please include your work so far, along with details about where your solution falls short. As great as your explanation may be, your actual code is the thing you need help with. If you're just looking for someone to write your code for you, then the question is off topic for StackOverflow. With the bash, awk and sed tags you've included, I'd expect to see some bash, awk and sed in your question.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. You mention you want to create an elegant one-line, but what did you try so far that does not fit on a single line? Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: How should, _We were drinking in bar922_ be handled? Or even more extreme, _bar bar922_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53827248/8344060) is really elegant and does not mess around too much. If you want to keep the ordering, you can extend it as:

```
$ { grep -wf wl file; grep -vf bl file ;} | grep -wf - file
```

notice that we introduced the `-w` flag for the whitelist to ensure word matches.

Remark: it is an eligant solution, it is by far the most efficient one!

Comment: That's a nice twist using the brace enclosed block. Changing `&&` to `;` will eliminate the issue you identified.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You just discovered a second issue. Indeed if the whitelist file is empty grep returns a failed status. Hence the semi-column is better. The issue I referred too, was the usage of the `-w` flag. Your example will match partial cases for the whitelist. The problem remains, however, how to identify full lines. Imagine the file contains "We were drinking in bar922", should this be matched or not?

Comment: That would match, but we could also use the `-o` (only matching)  output control option to eliminate `"We were drinking in "` -- another good catch by you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this little `awk` command for this. The idea is you use `paste` command on the blacklist file (`bl`) to make its contents separated by `|`, e.g. `bar|link` and also on the white-list file (`wl`).

Once the file is generated, we do a regex match on the contents of the file with a condition that, that those entries could be in white list or the entries should not be in the blacklist.

```
awk -v bl=$(paste -sd'|' bl) -v wl=$(paste -sd'|' wl) '$0 ~ wl || $0 !~ bl' file
```

There was a point in the comments, to handle empty lines in the `wl` file. If you suspect them, do fix them using `sed -i '/^$/d' wl`.

Comment: Nice solution...  interesting use of `paste` +1 :)

Comment: Nice, just avoid empty lines in wl or bl,

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple *one-liner* using `grep -f` to read patters from each your white and black list files and including the `-v` to invert the match with the black listings and then using the combined results on `stdin` to create the ordered file, e.g.

**Input, Whitelist, Blacklist Files**

```
$ cat file
foo123
bar12356
foo999
var8292
bar922
link991
bar8
var000
```

**Whitelist**

```
$ cat white
bar922
```

**Blacklist**

```
$ cat black
bar
link
```

**Edit**
After communicative work with @kvantour, you can feed the list for a final ordering on `stdin` making use of *process substitution* to obtain the final ordering, e.g,

```
$ grep -wof - file < <(grep -v -f black file; grep -f white file)
foo123
foo999
var8292
bar922
var000
```

Comment: This one doesn't preserve an original order

Comment: Oh yes, I saw the language but wasn't clear that you needed to preserve the order in the original file. This just returns the identified lines in the generic LOCALE sort order.

Comment: The closest you get here is simply reversing the order `grep -v -f black file && grep -f white file` which results in the last two items being reversed.

Comment: This is a very nice solution, disregarding the ordering!

Comment: Remark that this will fail if `file` contains a line `bar9222`

Comment: Yes, you could just chain them together as `grep -v -f black file; grep -f white file` to avoid the issue -- good catch.

Answer (score 0):

With Perl also, this can be addressed.

```
> cat stan.in
foo123
bar12356
foo999
var8292
bar922
link991
bar8
var000
> cat white
bar922
> cat black
bar
link
> perl -lne 'BEGIN{ @w=qx(cat white);@b=qx(cat black);}chomp for(@w);chomp for(@b); $x=$_;print if grep {$x=~/$_/} @w; print if scalar(grep { $x=~/$_/g} @b)==0' stan.in 
foo123
foo999
var8292
bar922
var000
>
```

or

```
$ perl -lne 'BEGIN{ @w=qx(cat white);@b=qx(cat black);}chomp for(@w,@b);$x=$_;print if grep {$x=~/$_/} @w; print if scalar(grep { $x=~/$_/g} @b)==0' stan.in
foo123
foo999
var8292
bar922
var000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, here's an option using bash arrays<sup>1</sup>:

```
# Gather our lists...
mapfile -t a < input.txt; mapfile -t wl < wl; mapfile -t bl < bl

# And store the whitelist as indices for easier handling...
declare -A wl_a=(); for x in "${wl[@]}"; do wl_a["$x"]=1; done

# Then step through the data array,
for x in "${!a[@]}"; do
  # detecting and skipping whitelist matches,
  [[ "${wl_a[${a[$x]}]}" = 1 ]] &&
    printf 'wl: %s\n' "$x" &&
    continue
  # and deleting blacklist matches.
  for y in "${bl[@]}"; do
    [[ "${a[$x]}" = "$y"* ]] &&
      printf 'bl: %s\n' "${a[$x]}" &&
      unset a["$x"]
  done
done
```

The result is that the array, `${a[@]}`, contains your data, in original order, with the appropriate blacklist items removed. You can see the result with `declare -p a` or `printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"`.

Note that this is a *crazy* way to achieve this (and it's obviously not a one-liner), you could do it much MUCH more efficiently in awk. But at least this is a pure bash solution, and uses no external tools, yay.

<sub>1. This depends on bash 4+, since one of the arrays is associative.</sub>